# SVG mask not working

Tags: svg, mask

I have an SVG vector object that consists of a few paths, some of which need to be masked.

For this I've made 5 SVG masks. All of them seem to be working (i.e. masking their respective object), except for one! I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

In short: how do I get the visible element within the circle to be properly masked? Any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

The object is up at this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNYOya

SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="het-lekkerste-van" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" width="504.789px" height="186.027px" viewBox="0 0 504.789 186.027" enable-background="new 0 0 504.789 186.027"
     xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <g id="l-masks">
        <mask id="mask-l-3">
            <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M59.644,94.138
                c0,0,70.4-35.679,57.122-49.875"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-l-2-2">
            <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M117.631,45.638
                c0,0-12.5-12.875-25,29.75"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-l-2-1">
            <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M92.144,74.763c0,0-16.375,62-41.75,59.5"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-l-1-2"> 
            <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M53.644,134.263
                c0,0-8.5,0.25-8-7.5c0,0,0.5-10.875,27.25-7.75"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="mask-l-1-1">
            <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M73.519,118.638
                c0,0,19.25,4.25,20.375,5.125c0,0,13.875,2.625,17,0.75c0,0,16.875-3.625,28.125-20.25"/>
        </mask>
    </g>
    <mask id="mask-cirkel">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="9" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M3.6829999999999927,93.014a89.013,89.013 0 1,0 178.026,0a89.013,89.013 0 1,0 -178.026,0"/>
    </mask>
</defs>

<path id="cirkel" style="mask: url(#mask-cirkel);" d="M92.696,186.027c-51.288,0-93.013-41.726-93.013-93.014S41.409,0,92.696,0s93.013,41.727,93.013,93.015
    S143.984,186.027,92.696,186.027z M92.696,8C45.82,8,7.683,46.137,7.683,93.014s38.137,85.014,85.013,85.014
    s85.013-38.137,85.013-85.014S139.573,8,92.696,8z"/>
<g id="l">
    <path id="l-1-1" style="mask: url(#mask-l-1-1);" d="M118.746,42.38l-3.498,5.077c0.135,0.371,0.228,0.785,0.228,1.29c0,1.65-0.766,3.502-2.271,5.494
        c-1.588,2.098-3.459,4.146-5.561,6.075c-2.14,1.962-4.335,3.812-6.527,5.482c-1.211,0.929-2.298,1.739-3.253,2.43c0,0,0,0,0,0.001
        c-3.865,2.9-8.178,5.521-8.178,5.521s0,0,0-0.001l-0.001,0.001c-2.521,1.682-5.14,3.347-7.78,4.97
        c-2.713,1.658-5.338,3.208-7.806,4.585c-2.527,1.424-4.851,2.702-6.899,3.815c-2.042,1.107-3.896,2.075-5.532,2.898
        c-1.55,0.843-1.875,1.933-1.875,2.695c0,1.421,0.898,2.271,2.402,2.271c0.198,0,0.511-0.032,1.315-0.308l0.124-0.055
        c2.767-1.469,6.344-3.409,10.936-5.924c3.87-2.13,7.981-4.514,12.254-7.1c0,0,3.608-2.058,8.171-5.201
        c1.803-1.205,4.122-2.822,6.905-4.802c2.9-2.066,5.806-4.412,8.63-6.972c2.823-2.557,5.296-5.258,7.348-8.021
        c2.117-2.846,3.188-5.67,3.188-8.385c0-2.021-0.543-3.74-1.62-5.114C119.234,42.836,118.996,42.599,118.746,42.38z"/>
    <path id="l-1-2" style="mask: url(#mask-l-1-2);" d="M97.864,68.228c0.496-1.402,1.083-2.975,1.756-4.702c1.073-2.747,2.342-5.44,3.771-7.994
        c1.407-2.516,3.021-4.69,4.799-6.467c1.699-1.701,3.532-2.527,5.604-2.527c0.656,0,1.084,0.158,1.274,0.465
        c0.08,0.131,0.124,0.299,0.18,0.454l3.498-5.077c-1.082-0.948-2.517-1.436-4.295-1.436c-3.45,0-6.563,1.297-9.253,3.849
        c-2.591,2.461-4.9,5.469-6.861,8.944c-1.938,3.439-3.663,7.063-5.119,10.768c-1.433,3.649-2.59,6.678-3.532,9.244
        c0.014-0.008,4.316-2.625,8.176-5.52C97.863,68.229,97.863,68.229,97.864,68.228z"/>
    <path id="l-2-1" style="mask: url(#mask-l-2-1);" d="M86.822,81.6c-0.608,1.686-1.287,3.558-2.038,5.631c-1.11,3.063-2.368,6.288-3.739,9.578
        c-1.383,3.332-2.929,6.773-4.587,10.227c-1.564,3.256-3.271,6.333-5.078,9.163c0,0,0,0,0,0s-1.403,2.627-3.389,5.012l0,0
        c0,0-0.001,0.001-0.001,0.001c-2.216,2.853-4.579,5.235-7.034,7.084c-2.675,2.015-5.534,3.042-8.5,3.079v5.547
        c4.053-0.26,7.848-1.707,11.29-4.329c3.621-2.764,7.031-6.359,10.148-10.693c1.939-2.555,3.326-4.936,3.326-4.936
        c1.71-2.868,3.364-5.915,4.928-9.076c1.76-3.563,3.426-7.209,4.958-10.843c1.524-3.621,2.968-7.261,4.291-10.828
        c1.281-3.458,2.478-6.733,3.595-9.817C90.43,79.544,86.822,81.6,86.822,81.6z"/>
    <path id="l-2-2" style="mask: url(#mask-l-2-2);" d="M52.291,131.382c-1.178,0-2.102-0.348-2.819-1.061c-0.719-0.719-1.068-1.549-1.068-2.541
        c0-1.418,0.448-2.518,1.372-3.369c0.998-0.914,2.239-1.623,3.694-2.102c1.507-0.502,3.077-0.84,4.667-1.003
        c1.61-0.174,2.947-0.26,3.971-0.26c1.305,0,2.573,0.021,3.763,0.064c0.715,0.026,1.426,0.061,2.122,0.1
        c1.985-2.385,3.388-5.011,3.388-5.011l0-0.001c-2.656-0.234-5.478-0.35-8.395-0.35c-1.783,0-3.841,0.18-6.118,0.537
        c-2.293,0.36-4.485,0.975-6.511,1.829c-2.072,0.875-3.854,2.117-5.29,3.692c-1.495,1.646-2.256,3.777-2.256,6.348
        c0,2.29,0.756,4.335,2.24,6.065c1.519,1.761,3.567,2.654,6.084,2.654c0.444,0,0.884-0.026,1.322-0.054v-5.547
        C52.401,131.375,52.346,131.382,52.291,131.382z"/>
    <path id="l-3" style="mask: url(#mask-l-3);" d="M138.434,105.592c-0.596-0.531-1.269-0.799-1.997-0.799c-0.925,0-1.74,0.346-2.472,1.084
        c-0.934,1.113-1.594,1.876-2.083,2.404c-0.52,0.563-0.994,1.06-1.426,1.49c-0.429,0.43-0.855,0.834-1.28,1.217
        c-0.433,0.391-1.037,0.889-1.833,1.506c-4.298,3.696-8.269,6.258-11.805,7.621c-3.537,1.362-7.044,2.056-10.432,2.056
        c-2.225,0-4.457-0.191-6.641-0.569c-2.228-0.383-4.533-0.876-6.849-1.466c-2.225-0.563-4.638-1.15-7.384-1.8
        c-2.223-0.526-4.577-0.983-7.013-1.37c0,0-1.387,2.381-3.326,4.936c2.967,0.426,5.808,0.951,8.452,1.559
        c2.845,0.66,5.584,1.323,8.144,1.974c2.651,0.67,5.217,1.229,7.627,1.655c2.476,0.448,5.003,0.67,7.516,0.67
        c3.862,0,7.838-0.77,11.813-2.291c3.972-1.519,8.364-4.262,13.052-8.154c0.884-0.703,1.613-1.303,2.192-1.79
        c0.582-0.5,1.154-1.019,1.7-1.562c0.568-0.575,1.178-1.229,1.808-1.949c0.659-0.745,1.519-1.729,2.533-2.919
        c0.415-0.416,0.634-0.937,0.634-1.505C139.365,106.832,139.044,106.139,138.434,105.592z"/>
</g>
<g id="het">
    <path d="M224.994,12.783h5.677v13.245h14.303V12.783h5.677v31.244h-5.677V30.913H230.67v13.114h-5.677L224.994,12.783
        L224.994,12.783z"/>
    <path d="M262.725,12.783h18.702v4.885h-13.025v8.186h10.518v4.885h-10.518v8.405h13.729v4.885h-19.405V12.783z"/>
    <path d="M301.654,17.668H291.4v-4.885h26.185v4.885h-10.254v26.359h-5.677V17.668z"/>
</g>
<g id="lekkerste">
    <path d="M224.994,75.983h5.677v26.358h13.511v4.886h-19.188V75.983z"/>
    <path d="M254.869,75.983h18.702v4.885h-13.025v8.186h10.519v4.885h-10.519v8.405h13.729v4.885h-19.406V75.983L254.869,75.983z"/>
    <path d="M286.329,75.983h5.677v12.718h4.049l7.35-12.718h6.161l-8.846,14.874v0.088l9.373,16.282h-6.381l-7.657-13.643h-4.049
        v13.643h-5.677V75.983L286.329,75.983z"/>
    <path d="M320.957,75.983h5.678v12.718h4.048l7.35-12.718h6.161l-8.846,14.874v0.088l9.373,16.282h-6.381l-7.657-13.643h-4.048
        v13.643h-5.678V75.983L320.957,75.983z"/>
    <path d="M355.583,75.983h18.702v4.885H361.26v8.186h10.518v4.885H361.26v8.405h13.729v4.885h-19.406V75.983z"/>
    <path d="M387.044,75.983h10.076c3.39,0,4.93,0.264,6.293,0.88c3.124,1.408,5.104,4.4,5.104,8.537c0,3.74-1.98,7.217-5.28,8.537
        v0.088c0,0,0.439,0.439,1.057,1.54l6.425,11.662h-6.337l-6.205-11.662h-5.456v11.662h-5.677V75.983z M397.825,90.637
        c3.036,0,4.93-1.805,4.93-4.93c0-2.992-1.276-4.84-5.722-4.84h-4.313v9.77H397.825L397.825,90.637z"/>
    <path d="M421.859,99.219c0,0,3.388,3.3,7.789,3.3c2.376,0,4.532-1.231,4.532-3.784c0-5.589-14.742-4.621-14.742-14.214
        c0-5.193,4.489-9.065,10.474-9.065c6.161,0,9.329,3.346,9.329,3.346l-2.464,4.619c0,0-2.992-2.729-6.909-2.729
        c-2.641,0-4.709,1.541-4.709,3.741c0,5.544,14.698,4.181,14.698,14.17c0,4.973-3.784,9.152-10.297,9.152
        c-6.953,0-10.782-4.269-10.782-4.269L421.859,99.219z"/>
    <path d="M459.16,80.868h-10.254v-4.885h26.185v4.885h-10.253v26.359h-5.678V80.868z"/>
    <path d="M485.383,75.983h18.702v4.885h-13.025v8.186h10.518v4.885h-10.518v8.405h13.729v4.885h-19.405V75.983z"/>
</g>
<g id="van">
    <path d="M220.989,139.184h6.117l6.864,20.375c0.615,1.804,1.145,4.576,1.188,4.576h0.088c0.044,0,0.572-2.772,1.188-4.576
        l6.908-20.375h6.072l-11.396,31.244h-5.633L220.989,139.184z"/>
    <path d="M273.792,162.419h-10.958l-2.641,8.01h-5.854l11.002-31.244h5.94l11.002,31.244h-5.854L273.792,162.419z M268.291,144.596
        c0,0-0.704,3.081-1.319,4.841l-2.772,8.36h8.186l-2.771-8.36c-0.572-1.76-1.232-4.841-1.232-4.841H268.291z"/>
    <path d="M292.445,139.184h5.677l11.838,18.042c1.188,1.805,2.597,4.841,2.597,4.841h0.088c0,0-0.308-2.992-0.308-4.841v-18.042
        h5.633v31.244h-5.633l-11.839-17.999c-1.188-1.805-2.597-4.841-2.597-4.841h-0.088c0,0,0.309,2.992,0.309,4.841v17.999h-5.677
        V139.184L292.445,139.184z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Which one is not working?  What's it supposed to look like?  Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It appears that path 'cirkel' draws a circular ring and that mask 'mask-cirkel' almost exactly matches the outer shape of that ring. So as written, path 'cirkel' gets drawn without any interference from the mask. Were you expecting something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the path definition of your 1-2-1 mask. If you replace that path definition with path definition of the l-2-1 shape it works perfectly. I can't see what's wrong myself - the original path seems to be perfectly valid and draws just fine outside a mask.